# Test Connectable Stream in Dart

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

I have the following `Stream`:

```dart
static Stream<FirebaseUser> _onAuthStateChangedOrReloaded =
    _mergeWithOnUserReloaded(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);

static Stream<FirebaseUser> _mergeWithOnUserReloaded(Stream<FirebaseUser> stream) {
  return Rx.merge([stream, onUserReloaded]).publishValue()..connect();
}
```

`publishValue()..connect()` make it a Connectable Stream, but I am having trouble trying to test it.

This is my **old test**, from before I made that stream a Connectable Stream:

```dart
test('Reloads emits the new User in onAuthStateChangedOrReloaded', () async {
  expect(FirebaseUserReloader.onAuthStateChangedOrReloaded, 
      emitsInOrder([mockOldUser, mockNewUser]));

  await FirebaseUserReloader.reloadCurrentUser();
});
```

But this test doesn't work with Connectable Streams, as test uses a `StreamQueue` and it needs to call `pause` on the stream, I get this error if I try:

```
dart:core                                              Object.noSuchMethod
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 472:19             StreamQueue._pause
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 434:7              StreamQueue._updateRequests
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 514:5              StreamQueue._addResult
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 484:9              StreamQueue._ensureListening.<fn>
dart:async                                             _EventSinkWrapper.add
package:rxdart/src/transformers/start_with.dart 18:17  _StartWithStreamSink.add
dart:async                                             _StreamSinkWrapper.add
package:rxdart/src/transformers/start_with.dart 59:13  _StartWithStreamSink._safeAddFirstEvent
package:rxdart/src/transformers/start_with.dart 40:13  _StartWithStreamSink.onListen
package:rxdart/src/utils/forwarding_stream.dart 18:22  forwardStream.<fn>
dart:async                                             _BoundSinkStream.listen
package:rxdart/src/streams/defer.dart 37:18            DeferStream.listen
dart:async                                             StreamView.listen
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 483:31             StreamQueue._ensureListening
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 542:7              StreamQueue._addRequest
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 299:5              StreamQueue.startTransaction
package:test_api                                       expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 234:3      expect
test\firebase_user_stream_test.dart 70:7               main.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                             _BoundSinkStream.listen
package:rxdart/src/streams/defer.dart 37:18            DeferStream.listen
dart:async                                             StreamView.listen
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 483:31             StreamQueue._ensureListening
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 542:7              StreamQueue._addRequest
package:async/src/stream_queue.dart 299:5              StreamQueue.startTransaction
package:test_api                                       expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 234:3      expect
test\firebase_user_stream_test.dart 70:7               main.<fn>.<fn>

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'pause' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: pause()
```

I was advised to use `expectAsync1`, but I can't make it work with `emitsInOrder`.

How can I test a Connectable Stream with `emitsInOrder`?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, you have to subscribe to the stream and make your own logic to test it. Add the expected results to a list and check them as they are emitted, you might have to call an empty future in order to trigger the emissions. It will be more manual code.

Comment: Thanks man, this solved it for me!